# display Javascript Date.toUTCString() with "Z" or "UTC" timezone

Tags: javascript, reactjs, datetime

In my React app, a Date component's `.toUTCString()` displays its timezone as "GMT". This is wrong -- Greenwich Mean Time is not the same as UTC: GMT is a timezone, UTC is a time standard, plus the method is literally called 'toUTCString' not 'toGMTstring'. In my industry it is standard to refer to UTC as 'Zulu' time and display the TZ suffix with a 'Z'.

Is there anyway to control this behaviour? Currently I'm writing custom formatters and I'm little tired of having to use them.

update: Just to point out I'm talking about 'human readable' on-screen formats; the ISO8601 format from `.toISOString()` isn't human readable. `.toUTCString()` *nearly* works for a reasonable default; as it is I'm using `moment` to format every date when, if not for a javascript bug with mishandling 'UTC', there would be a sensible default.

Comment: Date#toJSON or Date#toISOString is probably what you want

Comment: hi @charlietfl - not quite, it's not human readable. adjusted the question to clarify.

Comment: do not adjust your set, the output is correct. `GMT` just means `+0` and is an accepted timezone indicator. If you don't need to reparse it later, then a String replace or complex lib formatter can be used as needed.

Comment: moment `format()` will make it human readable

Comment: Hi @dandavis, I work for airline. GMT is a timezone we do not use to refer to anything in our industry. It is not accepted. Aircraft movements are tracked in either  port-local (Local) or in Zulu time. Also it's not the same thing as UTC.

Comment: @charlitfl yes that's what I've had to resort to. However everything with the default format is fine, except for the incorrect timezone indicator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer appears to be there is not control over what is printed by the method. The fact that the method is *called* `toUTCString` yet *prints* `GMT` in the output is just apparently another one of those glaring, and stupid, inconsistencies one encounters in programming languages.

Answer (score 2):

It appears that "GMT" is the technical name for the time zone, whereas "UTC" is the standard. People often confuse the latter for a time zone, which is [not correct](https://www.worldtimeserver.com/learn/utc-vs-gmt/#:%7E:text=In%20short%2C%20GMT%20is%20an,time%20synchronized%20across%20the%20world.&text=Since%20Coordinated%20Universal%20Time%20or,it%20for%20a%20local%20time.).

> Since Coordinated Universal Time or UTC is a standard, there is no time zone, territory or country that uses it for a local time. Greenwich Mean Time or GMT is the official time zone used in that region, which runs through several European and African countries. Coordinated Universal Time is named as such because it is the standard by which all time zones are based. Contrary to popular belief, UTC is a standard even though it is mistaken for a time zone, which it is not.

That's why `toUTCString` is technically correct, because it's displaying a UTC-type string that uses the GMT time zone (not the "UTC time zone").

Answer (score 1):

Does toISOString() do what you want?

Comment: Hello and welcome to stack overflow! You are likely correct, however you need to phrase this as an answer, preferably with sample output like `new Date().toISOString() // "2018-05-19T00:02:54.853Z"`

Comment: Not quite. I use ISOString for 'technical' formatting but I'm talking 'human readable' on screen formats. toUTCString() *nearly* works for a reasonable default; as it is I'm using moment to format nearly every date.